# Getting Star Wars - Rogue Squadron working on linux

Tags: wine, games, emulation

I've tried using mupen64plus and project64 2.0 under wine, but both have failed to run correctly.  The video is completely blank, although the audio seems to run fine.  Even when I fullscreen the project64 window, it still remains blank, only changing colour from black to white.

I've tried various video plugins, including arachnoid, z64, rice, glide64, etc.

Rice comes the closest, by showing small parts of the screen, with the rest being totally blank.

Glide64 outputs an error message:

```
Video: ucode = -1
Video Error: Error: Unsupported uCode!
crc: 86b1593e
```

I've also tried the different available varieties of the game, the USA and European versions, but to no avail.

Not sure where to go from there.

Edit: I'm using nvidia proprietary drivers and have had no problem running other games in both mupen64plus and project64 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Do your current drivers support 3D acceleration?** If you're running other games in Wine, then the answer is likely yes. If you aren't, or you don't know or otherwise want a sanity check, open terminal and run `glxgears`. For modern graphics cards, the gears demo should run, and the output should show an FPS well over 1000.

If your current drivers don't support 3D acceleration, you'll need to install ones that do. This will depend on your card, but generally, the easiest way is to install the proprietary drivers. You can find them in the "Drivers" tab of the "Additional Software Sources" app.

**Have you tried PlayOnLinux?** PlayOnLinux is a wrapper for Wine that's available in the respositories. It can aid in getting games to work by installing specific versions of Wine (they don't overwrite one another) that are known to work best for the application in question. Often, this is one of the easiest ways to get a game working.

Comment: Yes, I'm using nvidia drivers and am able to play every other game I've tried to.  It's only this game which is being so problematic.

Comment: Have you tried PlayOnLinux? If not, try it. Also, a quick search on WineHQ for reviews of the game shows that it has, at best, a bronze rating. The reviews for it are old, though, so it's possible the things keeping it from working have since been fixed. However, that should be something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! Wine has recently gained the ability to play the Microsoft Windows version which is almost identical to the N64 version. I tested it with Wine 4.12.1 and a downloadable version of *Rogue Squadron 3D* I purchased from [GOG.com](https://www.gog.com/game/star_wars_rogue_squadron_3d). It worked well with two hitches:

- Disable the d3d11 library using an override in winecfg. Wine will use d3d9 instead, which has much smoother animation (higher FPS).
- The standard camera starts lagging behind the player's ship and does not catch up properly. The fix is to hit "F1" so you have the "Close View" instead. (From the reviews, this bug is a problem for Microsoft Windows as well.)